# Manual WebJob SDK function binding

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a Service Bus queue that I want to consume off of.  All of the samples I have found recommend writing something like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static String ServiceBusConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    static void Main()
    {
        var jobHostConfiguration = new JobHostConfiguration
        {
            ServiceBusConnectionString = ServiceBusConnectionString,
        };
        var jobHost = new JobHost(jobHostConfiguration);
        jobHost.RunAndBlock();
    }
}

public class QueueItem
{
    public String Name;
    public Int64 Id;
}

public class Functions
{
    public void ProcessQueueItem([ServiceBusTrigger("queue-name")] QueueItem queueItem)
    {
        // TODO: process queue item
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that the queue name is hard coded in my program.  I want to be able to get the queue name from configuration like I do with the queue connection string.  Unfortunately, attributes can only be passed compile time constants, so I can't pass in some statically initialized string that comes from configuration.

I looked around a bit and was unable to find any other way to setup Service Bus function binding.  Is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `INameResolver` to accomplish what you want.

One of the official samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations) covers exactly your scenario. Take a look the `ShutdownMonitor` function in `Functions.cs` and then at the `ConfigNameResolver` class.